# puppeteer identifying element content after click event

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, puppeteer

I'm trying to extract a particular element from a page after inputting a query and clicking a button.  The page does not navigate to a new URL: it just returns new HTML content that I need to extract.

This describes how far I've got:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

const input_val = 'some query text';

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://target.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    await page.waitFor('input[name=query]')

    await page.evaluate((input_val) => {
      document.querySelector('input[name=query]').value = input_val;
      document.querySelector('.Button').click();
    }, input_val)

    // Now I want to console.log the <strong> tag fields 
    // innerText (will be 0-3 matching elements).
    // The lines below describe in non-puppeteer what 
    // I need to do. But this has no effect.

    const strongs = await page.$$('strong')
    for(var i=0; i<strongs.length; i++) {
      console.log(strongs[i].innerText);
    }

    await timeout(2000)
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'}) // this renders results page ok

    browser.close();
})();
```

So the input query is being input correctly, the button click is firing, and the screenshot shows the webpage has responded as expected.  I just can't figure out how to extract and report the relevant bits.

I have been trying to get my head around the whole async/await paradigm, but I'm still pretty new to it.  Assistance much appreciated.

---

Edit - Vaviloff method error:

```
(node:67405) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Cannot find context with specified id undefined
    at Promise (/Users/user/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:200:56)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (/Users/user/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:199:12)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (/Users/user/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:79:75)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluate (/Users/user/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:46:31)
    at Frame.evaluate (/Users/user/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:326:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
(node:67405) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:67405) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Please update the question with your current script so that we can debug. Maybe a typo or a missed `await` somewhere. Also: what is your puppeteer version? Some old versions have [a bug producing this error](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1325).

Comment: I've added a working script for testing the technique.

Comment: I've just done one too - https://gist.github.com/diplodata/8d02c40d5038948371a28b3ef513ca30

Comment: For me, changing `await page.goto(url);` to `await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });` fixed the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a useful helper utility [page.$$eval](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args):

> This method runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the page and passes it as the first argument to pageFunction.

Since it passes an Array to the evaluated function we can use `.map()` on it to extract a needed attribute:

```
const strongs = await page.$$eval('strong', items => items.map( item => item.innerText));
```

**Update**
Here's a full working script for testing:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const input_val = '[puppeteer]';
const items_selector = '.question-hyperlink';

(async() => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    await page.waitFor('input[name=q]')
    await page.type('input[name=q]', input_val + '\r');
    await page.waitForNavigation();

    const items = await page.$$eval(items_selector, items => items.map( item => item.innerText));

    console.log(items);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

**Update 2**
A modified version of the script for the sandbox at https://diplodata.shinyapps.io/puppeteer-test/

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const input_val = 'puppeteer';

(async() => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto('https://diplodata.shinyapps.io/puppeteer-test/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    await page.waitFor('#query')
    await page.type('#query', input_val);
    await page.click('#go');
    await page.waitFor(500);
    const items = await page.$$eval('strong', items => items.map( item => item.innerText));

    console.log(items);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Produces the following result:

> [ 'On click below should read:', '<query>', 'puppeteer ' ]

Comment: Thanks Vaviloff. This throws an error for me - see above.

Comment: This is useful. Nothing printing in console however. It runs 30s then returns ```(node:93096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (/Users/robinedwards/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/NavigatorWatcher.js:73:21)
    at <anonymous>
(node:93096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:93096) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning...```

Comment: Modified the script specifically for your sandbox.

Comment: It works! Awesome. So (at least part of) my script failure seems to have been how I was reporting. e.g. `for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) { console.log(items[i]); }` prints everything except "puppeteer".

Comment: You can use `await page.waitFor(500)` instead of custom `await timeout(500);` function

Comment: @OlegAbrazhaev True that